# is there a way to check if a cookie has an expiration date?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

is there a way to find out whether a cookie is a session-cookie or a cookie with expiration time?
(best with the use of jQuery)

thank you!

Comment: not exactly the same. 
I am not trying to get the expiration time, but to determine whether the cookie even has an expiration time set, or is it a session cookie.
That - just might be doable. I don't know.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same maybe – but it comes down to the same thing: Nope, not possible.